# One object write to stream, second object read from the same stream

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a part of program that has an object that does some calculations and then uses one method (when each calculation is done) to write to Console.

I would like to change the output of this function to some kind of stream that other object would be able to read from (without that object knowing when the method is being called by the object doing the output).

Is this possible?

Comment: Check out [RedirectStandardInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why a stream? Are the objects in different processes?

Comment: Because I need the program to be stateless and from my understanding if I would just "print" to property then it would be not

Comment: Consider using [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/).